# Does every semi-positive definite matrix correspond to a covariance matrix?

Tags: covariance, matrix

It is well-known that a covariance matrix must be semi-positive definite, however, is the converse true?

That is, does every semi-positive definite matrix correspond to a covariance matrix?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Going by the definitions of PD and PSD [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), yes, I think so, since we can do this by construction. I'll assume for a slightly simpler argument that you mean for matrices with real elements, but with appropriate changes it would extend to complex matrices.

Let $A$ be some real PSD matrix; from the definition I linked to, it will be symmetric. Any real symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ can be written as $A = LL^T$. This can be done by $L=Q\sqrt{D}Q^T$ if $A=QDQ^T$ with orthogonal $Q$ and diagonal $D$ and $\sqrt{D}$ as matrix of component wise square roots of $D$. Thus, it needn't be full rank.

Let $Z$ be some vector random variable, of the appropriate dimension, with covariance matrix $I$ (which is easy to create).

Then $LZ$ has covariance matrix $A$.

[At least that's in theory. In practice there'd be various numerical issues to deal with if you wanted good results, and - because of the usual problems with floating point calculation - you'd only approximately get what you need; that is, the population variance of a computed $LZ$ usually wouldn't be *exactly* $A$. But this sort of thing is always an issue when we come to actually calculate things]

Comment: While it is true that a decomposition $A=LL'$ is possible without full rank, the Cholesky algorithm only works with regular $A$. So without full rank, it cannot be a Cholesky decomposition. Computationally, one could do this decomposition in the singular case by diagonalization. (Although this is far more expensive)

Comment: @Horst: Why would $L=Q\sqrt{D}Q^T$ be lower triangular?

Comment: @amoeba While one could organize it so it is, it doesn't have to be lower triangular for the argument to work - it's a feature of the Cholesky but it's not required for the result to work.

Comment: @Glen_b: Precisely. So the answer, as it reads now (after the edit), contains a mistake.

Comment: @Glen Is being symmetric a necessary condition for being PSD or is that definition one of many?

Comment: @amoeba: One lesson in proper answering and editing to me: Omit as much as possible. Then it will be a great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @amoeba and Horst. I came back this morning (my time) to fix it up and ... it's all done.

Comment: @114 for the relation between symmetric and PSD see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516533/symmetric-vs-positive-semidefinite